# File System Error: An error occurred while opening the <path name> local cube file

Tags: vb6

I am using Windows 8 64-Bit

I am attempting to build an ADODC Connection String on VB 6.

When I go to the ADODC Properties window and go to "Connection String", I build a string by entering the path name and testing the connection. There is no problem with the connection. In the path name, I enter the location of the .mdb file which I want to connect to my VB 6.

Even though the test connection is okay, when I click "apply", I get the error: File System Error: An error occurred while opening the  local cube file.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: is it pure Access or does it connect to SQL Server?

Comment: Your problem can because of many reasons; I write two answer and I think both are useful, But in another reasons It can be result of your `Installing Office` or `MDac_Type` or etc. too.

Answer (score 0):

It can be for more reasons:

I add some sample `ConnectionString` that you can paste them without setting and applying:
UsingMicrosoft Jet OLE DB 4.0:
`Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;User Id=admin;
Password=;`

Using Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0:
`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.mdb;
Persist Security Info=False;`

Using Microsoft Access accdb ODBC Driver:
`Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\mydatabase.mdb;`

Using Microsoft Access ODBC Driver:
`Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=C:\mydatabase.mdb;Uid=Admin;Pwd=;`

for more connection strings use [This Link](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2003/).

Answer (score 0):

For checking your setting in windows follow this:

- Add a new `Text Document` -anywhere-
- Rename `New Text Document.txt` to `testConnection.udl` -just extension is important-
- In the same window of `ADODC settings` windows; set your own settings.
- Test your own Connection settings by <kbd>Test Connection</kbd>.
- If it's OK! press <kbd>OK</kbd>.
- Open `testConnection.udl` by `NotePad`:

  [oledb]
  ; Everything after this line is an OLE DB initstring
  Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;User Id=admin; Password=;
- Copy the last line to your `ConnectionString` property of ADODC.

Comment: It is possible that you have a same raising error in Apply or OK; then try another provider.